# pandas groupby apply/tranform operation to do manipulation per group

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe like this:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'year': [1990,1990,1992,1992,1992],
                  'value': [100,200,300,400,np.nan],
                  'rank': [2,1,2,1,3]})
print(df)
   year  value  rank
0  1990  100.0     2
1  1990  200.0     1
2  1992  300.0     2
3  1992  400.0     1
4  1992    NaN     3
```

I am trying to achieve this:

```
# For year 1990, maximum value is 200, rank is 1 and also relative value is 1.

   year  value  rank  value_relative
0  1990  100.0     2  0.5
1  1990  200.0     1  1
2  1992  300.0     2  0.75
3  1992  400.0     1  1
4  1992    NaN     3  NaN
```

My attempt:

```
df['value_relative'] = df.groupby('year')['value'].transform(lambda x: x/x[x.rank == 1]['value'])
```

How can we do this operation where we calculate relative value for each year?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC using `transform` with `first` after `sort_values`

```
df['value_relative']=df.value/df.sort_values('rank').groupby('year').value.transform('first')
df
Out[60]: 
   year  value  rank  value_relative
0  1990  100.0     2            0.50
1  1990  200.0     1            1.00
2  1992  300.0     2            0.75
3  1992  400.0     1            1.00
4  1992    NaN     3             NaN
```

Or just do `transform` `max`

```
df['value_relative']=df.value/df.groupby('year').value.transform('max')
```

---

Another method

```
df.value/df.loc[df.groupby('year')['rank'].transform('idxmin'),'value'].values
Out[64]: 
0    0.50
1    1.00
2    0.75
3    1.00
4     NaN
Name: value, dtype: float64
```

---

If you need 2nd rank as denominator

```
df.value/df.year.map(df.loc[df['rank']==2].set_index('year')['value'])
```

The different here is depends on how you get your rank , if is base on max of value , then both of them should return the same result , but if that is a given rank none related to the value columns , then you should using `first`

Comment: Generalization, how to do when `rank = 2` ? I know when rank is 1, I can simply divide by maximum value.

Comment: @astro123 as I mentioned , I using the sort_values and the first, also I have added another method using idxmin

Comment: For  `rank = 2`  I tried `transform('second')`  and `transform('nth(2))` but failed.

Comment: @astro123 that should be nth(1), also if you like to find the 2nd, do with `df.year.map(df.loc[df['rank']==2].set_index('year')['value'])
`

Comment: Sadly, this failed for me `df.value/df.sort_values('rank').groupby('year').value.transform('nth(1)')`

Comment: @astro123 nope, the index need to match

Comment: I did it and got the exact answer like you, I also updated my simple answer.

Comment: @astro123 Ohh I see, you do it within lambda :-) , but just a kindly suggestion , lambda will slowing down the whole process .

Comment: Thanks for the valuable info, I will try to avoid lambda and surely follow your approach, I was just trying multiple simple ways to do the things disregarding efficiency.

Answer (score 1):

I liked and accepted the Wen's answer, but wanted to give my 2 cents:

The simplest method is just divide value by maximum, but I am trying to learn doing this using separate column called rank:

```
df.groupby('year')['value'].transform(lambda x: x/x.max())
0    0.50
1    1.00
2    0.75
3    1.00
4     NaN
```

Another simple method for rank ==2:

```
df.groupby('year')['value'].transform(lambda x: x/x.nlargest(2).iloc[-1])
0    1.000000
1    2.000000
2    1.000000
3    1.333333
4         NaN
```

NOTE: Wen's method:

```
df.value/df.year.map(df.loc[df['rank']==2].set_index('year')['value'])
    0    1.000000
    1    2.000000
    2    1.000000
    3    1.333333
    4         NaN
```